# Adding security permission for service in manifest file for Oreo+

Tags: android, android-service-binding, android-job

I had a service which other apps used to bind with. And to secure this i have added a permision for the service. As a part of making the my app to Oreo compatible i have to change that service to JobService. To do so i had to add the permission(BIND_JOB_SERVICE) for my service in manifest. Now the problem is, I already have my security permission addded for that service to allow other appps to securely bind to my service hence i am left with adding only one permission to be added.
Here is the service in manifest

```
<service
        android:exported="true"
        android:name=".features.upload_datastream.DataStreamingService"
        android:permission="com.example.permission.IMMEDIATE_DATA_UPLOAD">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.example.features.upload_datastream.DataStreamServiceImpl"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

How can i add both `com.example.permission.IMMEDIATE_DATA_UPLOAD` and `android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE` permissions for the service?

Comment: are you able to add BIND_JOB_SERVICE in your custom permission ? than it may solve your problem.

Comment: @MaheshKeshvala No, can't add that way